Subject: DLL Load Failed Error When Importing cv2 on Windows 11 Pro
I am using Python 3.12 and OpenCV 4.10 on Windows 11 Pro. My code, which was working fine previously, started giving a "DLL load failed" error when importing cv2 this morning. The same code was working without issues before. What should I do to resolve this problem? What solutions would you recommend for this situation?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ...\Masaüstü\heatmap\heatmapp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.


Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)

crosspost including resolution: https://forum.opencv.org/t/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2-on-windows-11-pro/18064

The following steps worked for me.
Go to Windows, then Settings and click Uninstall/Install Apps.
Go to Optional Features.
Go to Add button.
Look for Windows Media Pack.
Install if needed and then reinstall OpenCV

I followed the steps you mentioned, but Windows Media Pack is not showing up for me. When I try to download and install it, I get an error saying it's not suitable for my system.

Try Uninstalling and reinstalling the module without Media Pack installation. Then run the code

It seems that I do not have Windows 11N, so it is not installing.

Do you mean the module is not installing, or the Media Pack. If the media pack, don't bother installing it. Just try uninstalling and re-installing the module and run the code
